# Model accuracy changes when target attribute change

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I have a dataset. For a target attribute for example:person, I get an accuracy which is different when I use for example:price as target attribute and so on.

Why this accuracy keep changing?

Answer (score 1):

There is not reason to believe that the accuracy wouldn't change as you change the target. After all, the features that is able to explain a target distribution could be very different from the features that is able to explain another target distribution.

It is similar to how human learn. We can't expect a human who is just trained to speak English to suddenly speak fluently in another language.